# Hide div on custom page(url) load/open?

Tags: css, wordpress, html, hide

On my web page [NicoComerc](http://nicocomerc.com/) when u open it, there is custom div at bottom left position to show "traditional pasta" - girl on every page that u open.
But i want to hide that div when u open this [URL](http://nicocomerc.com/?portfolio=perun) from the left menu. (that url is > Производи > Потпалувачи) <- sry its macedonian language...

So is it possible to do it, and if so... how to make that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>


$(function(){

var url = window.location.pathname;

if (url.toLowerCase().indexOf("portfolio=perun") >= 0){
$("#devojka").remove();
}

});
</script>
```

Required JQuery, but you already have it

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. You can do that by checking if the url fits some pattern. In javascript, one way to achieve that is the following one ...

**Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    if(window.location.search == "?page_id=2762" || window.location.search == "?portfolio=perun" ) { 
        $('#devojka').css('display','none'); 
    } 
</script>
```

You are calling the script too soon in your page. When `$('#devojka')` is executed, the element (devojka) is not in page yet.

Move you script to the bottom of the page or wrap your code to the `window.onload`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    window.onload = function() {
        if(window.location.search == "?page_id=2762" || window.location.search == "?portfolio=perun" ) { 
            $('#devojka').css('display','none'); 
        }
    } 
</script>
```

More about **window.location**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

Comment: My div id is "devojka" and i add your code, change "page_id=12" with my url where i want to hide the dive, but not working :S

Answer (score 0):

I would add a query string to the link in the menu (`/menu/item?hide_div=1`).  Then you can check for the existence of string on the server side or with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write JavaScript/JQuery such as the following

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?) (&|#|;|$)').exec(
             location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}
$(function() {
    if (getURLParameter('portfolio') == 'потпалувачи-перун') {
        $('#id-of-div-to-hide').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I try that, added those JS code to the main JS file, and i even rename my portfolio to "perun" so its not cyrilic, and its not working ... :S

Comment: what sort of error are you getting? Like what part of it isn't working?